# ffmpeg - set pts for vfr video from list of values

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp, h.264, pts

I have a list of timestamps in milliseconds that I want to apply as the PTS values of a video stream.   The video is a h264 stream without a container and I want to stream copy into an MKV with the PTS values from a text file.

The video has a variable frame rate that I want to maintain precisely. Is this possible?

Comment: https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html#mkvmerge.external_timestamp_files

Comment: Thanks @Gyan this works nicely.  Should I take this to mean that it's not possible within ffmpeg directly?

Comment: Yes, not trivially possible to assign timestamps from an external resource.